# Changing to static IP?

Tags: server

I'm using Ubuntu Server and trying to set my connection to have a static IP, instead of a dynamic one.  However, whenever I enter this into 
*/etc/network/interface*

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.68
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.1.64
```

My server can't connect to the internet.  Running something like *sudo apt-get upgrade*, gives errors because I'm not connected to the internet.  What's wrong with this?

Comment: You have no DNS addresses (nameservers).  I don't know how to do this for servers, but it used to be done in resolv.conf.  Not sure if it still is

Comment: Well, for starters let us figure out whatever this is about being able to connect to the Interenet, or about being able to resolve DNS lookups. Please try pinging 8.8.8.8 (or some other good known ip address) and update the question with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as from 12.04LTS one should not use `/etc/resolv.conf`. If a network adapter is working with IP addresses, but doesn't resolve domain names, add

```
dns-nameservers 1.2.3.4  5.6.7.8
```

after *gateway* clause in `/etc/network/interface`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify DNS servers. When DHCP is enabled, your server gets this information automatically, which won't work with a static IP.

Comment: I just tried doing that, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: See if you can ping your default gateway and the DNS servers. That should help identify whether the problem is on your network or with the DNS. Use the dig command to test your DNS configuration. If this is the problem, you might want to try different servers, such as Google public DNS at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Ubuntu Server Guide, you do indeed modify /etc/network/interfaces as follows.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4
dns-search mydomain.com
```

Then shutdown and restart the interface:

```
~$ sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html#ip-addressing